# Static positioned menu and z-index issue, need to keep my jquery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have made a menu which is perfect, the only problem I am having is that my submenu will sit under specific elements on my website. This is because my menu is positioned "static" so my z-index does not apply to my .sub-menu (child).

What I do not want to do is go around my website and set various elements to have a z-index of -1 or something like that.

What I also need to do is keep my jQuery slideup/down animations.

I have tried to position my menu with relative instead of static, but I am having some problems with my jQuery animation. I have also tried putting a top-level div above everything and still no luck - is there anyway around this? What should I do, I'm stumped.

HTML:

```
<div class="nt-main-navigation">
  <div class="nt-main-nav-animation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nt-main-navigation-wrapper clearfix">

            <!-- My menu, submenu (theproblem), logo, etc in here -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Header Style 1 */

.activeScroll .nt-main-navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.nt-main-navigation {
    -webkit-transition: top 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: top 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: top 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: top 500ms ease;
    transition: top 500ms ease;
    position: static;

   /* fix laggy transition */
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   -o-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
}

.nt-main-nav-animation {
    position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
// HEADER STYLE 1

// get header height
var getHeaderHeight = $('.nt-main-navigation').outerHeight();
var getToolbarHeight = $('.nt-toolbar-wrap').outerHeight();

// init last scroll position
var lastScrollPosition = 0;

// set container top property on page load with static position
$('.nt-main-navigation').css('top', '-' + getHeaderHeight + 'px');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    // At +100px menu slides down page
    if($(window).scrollTop() > getHeaderHeight + getToolbarHeight + 100) {

        $('body').addClass('activeScroll').css('padding-top', getHeaderHeight);
        $('.nt-main-navigation').css('top', 0);

        if(currentScrollPosition < lastScrollPosition) {
            $('.nt-main-navigation').css('top', '-' + getHeaderHeight + 'px');
        }

        lastScrollPosition = currentScrollPosition;

    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('activeScroll').css('padding-top', 0);
    }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank-you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to tell what's going on without a demo or codepen, but here are my thoughts.

z-index only effects elements that have a position value **other** than static. It doesn't look like you have anything set on the `.nt-main-navigation` class. I'd try adding the following:

```
.nt-main-navigation {position:relative; z-index:500;}
```

Now, `position:relative;` doesn't actually do anything **unless** a top, left, bottom, etc value is set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into this, and next time I have a question will make sure to set up a codepen. Thankyou.